# SQL Server 2016 SP1 - Is this a bug?

Tags: sql-server, persistent, sql-server-2016

I just installed SQL Server 2016 and SP1 and run this TSQL Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TEST(
[id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[lat] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
[lng] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
[Location]  AS ([geography]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT ('+[lng])+' ')+[lat])+')',(4326))) 
    PERSISTED
)
```

The table is created fine.

I then run the following (there is no records in the table)

```
Select * from TEST
```

This returns

**Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 8
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**

It is related to the `Location` field.

**Is this a bug in SQL Server 2016?**  I would not expect this behavior.

The following does not cause any issues

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TEST2(
[id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[lat] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
[lng] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
[Location]  AS [lng] PERSISTED
)

select * from TEST2
```

Comment: It also fails the same on SQL-Server 2014

Comment: You can't do this, so why would you expect to do this as a computed column? `SELECT [geography]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT ('+12)+' ')+93)+')',(4326))` - seems like you'll need to populate the values using a trigger with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
[Location] AS ([geography]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT (' + [lng]) + ' ') + [lat]) + ')', (4326)))
```

to

```
[Location] AS ([geography]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT (' + CAST([lng] AS varchar)) + ' ') + CAST([lat] AS varchar)) + ')', (4326)))
```

The difference in these two are the usage of the `CAST` function like so:

```
CAST([lng] AS varchar)
CAST([lat] AS varchar)
```

Simply an issue of `[lng]` and `[lat]` being decimals concatenated to a varchar string. The reason for it not being a problem until you actually execute the query even with no data in the table is due to the `[Location]` field not being formed until the select query is executed.

Not a bug necessarily but something that SQL Management Studio should probably parse for prior to executing the `CREATE TABLE` query.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `CAST` the lng and lat values to varchar so the `+` operator is treated as concatenation instead of addition. Example without the extraneous parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TEST(
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lat] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
    [lng] [DECIMAL](9, 6) NULL,
    [Location]  AS [geography]::STGeomFromText('POINT ('+ CAST([lng] AS varchar(10)) + ' ' + CAST([lat] AS varchar(10)) + ')', 4326) 
        PERSISTED
    );
```